# how to add user in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello guys am working on project and i have made component addusers i try this on postman with api it works perfectly. but when i implement in code its giving error (Failed to add user: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddUser = ({ setTokenValue }) => {
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsSubmitting(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://api.store.ellcart.com/users", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer <eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwaS5zdG9yZS5lbGxjYXJ0LmNvbS91c2Vycy9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY4NTYzNDY1MCwibmJmIjoxNjg1NjM0NjUwLCJqdGkiOiJBZ2doWFpiT1VxeGF4QTBvIiwic3ViIjoiMjA0IiwicHJ2IjoiMjNiZDVjODk0OWY2MDBhZGIzOWU3MDFjNDAwODcyZGI3YTU5NzZmNyJ9.28tizEstlORenFGcDin-3RSFgtHzJpnoA2UYI7A2sJ0>`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: name,
          email: email,
          phone: phone,
          password: password,
        }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to add user");
      }

      const data = await response.json();

      if (data && data.authorisation && data.authorisation.access_token) {
        const token = data.authorisation.access_token;
        setTokenValue(token);
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setPhone("");
        setPassword("");
        setErrorMessage("");
      }
    } catch (error) {

      setErrorMessage(error.message);
      console.error("Failed to add user:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsSubmitting(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Phone:
        <input type="phone" value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <label>
        Password:
        <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting}>
        {isSubmitting ? "Submitting..." : "Add User"}
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddUser;
```

i request please help me to get my fact clear.

Comment: check what the request is returning in your browsers *developer* tools - chances are, it's `const data = await response.json();` failing because it looks like the response is a web page (html) not the JSON you seem to expect - I hope `"prv": "23bd5c8949f600adb39e701c400872db7a5976f7"` in the jwt isn't private ...

Comment: Your response.ok goes well and as @JaromandaX said an exception is being raised because response.json() is failing cause response return is not json but html. Its recommended to use fetch() promise and only try to parse response to json if success code is received like fetch().then(response => if(response.status !== 200) return; return response.json()).then(data => if(!data) return; console.log(data);))

Comment: can u write me full code